# SQL запрос бесконечно экзекьютится

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 такие таблицы:
SatisDetay

```
Depo    SatisID SatisSira   UrunID    Satici    KdvKod  KDVYuzde    Miktar
AZ01    20001   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20002   1           3788898   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   1           3876390   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   2           3793202   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   3           4046508   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   4           3843387   999       AZ       18.00      1
AZ01    20003   5           3850608   999       AZ       18.00      1
```

И DepoSevkDetay

```
BaslikID    Sira    UrunID   Miktar Fiyat   Depo
20001       1       3792703  1      1       AZ01  
20002       1       4067131  1      1       AZ01  
20003       1       3251881  1      1       AZ01  
20003       2       3251883  1      1       AZ01  
20003       3       3788887  1      1       AZ01  
20003       4       3788890  1      1       AZ01  
20004       1       3761260  2      1       AZ01
```

Задача стоит такая: Взять Сумму Miktar для каждого UrunID и распределить во второй таблице так, чтобы общая сумма там равнялась бы общей суме в первой. При этом количество записей могут не совпадать. 
Я пока не знаю как распределить этот самый SUM во второй таблице, учитывая что количество записей не совпадает. Но тревожит то, что даже простой запрос

```
 UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.[Miktar] = Table_B.[Miktar]
FROM
    [Retail].[dbo].[tb_DepoSevkDetay] AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT [Miktar], [UrunID] FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
                GROUP BY [UrunID], [Miktar] ) AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.[UrunID] = Table_B.[UrunID]
```

Экзекьютится вечно. Помогите пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: Посмотрите на подзапрос - он Вам не кажется... ммм... странным? Вы правда хотите просто избавиться от дублей? Да и сам UPDATE с учётом неуникальности UrunID тоже не очень... А условие `распределить во второй таблице так, чтобы общая сумма там равнялась бы общей суме в первой` вообще непонятно - ведь после Вашего UPDATE старые значения Miktar будут перезаписаны, так что чему равняться-то?

Comment: Все, что нужно - это чтобы сумма Miktar для каждого UrunID в обоих таблицах была равной и бралась из именно SatisDetay

Comment: Ну тогда алгоритмически это получится как-то так: 1) в подзапросах в группах по `UrunID` считаем `SUM(SatisDetay.Miktar)`, в другом `COUNT(DepoSevkDetay.UrunID)` и `ROW_NUMBER()` по ней же. 2) выполняем обновление, присваиваем каждому `DepoSevkDetay.Miktar` значение `SUM \ COUNT + CASE WHEN (SUM % COUNT < ROW_NUMBER()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Первый компонент раскидывает равномерно по всем, а второй раскидывает остаток. Возможно, там не "<", а наоборот, или нестрого, или единичку прибавить-отнять ещё - но думать лень, а пробовать сейчас негде.